# Using `apply` make `when` exhaustive, when setting contentDescription

Tags: android, kotlin

So i am trying to refactor code in recyclerView adapter, and it uses 2 viewType based on position. But when im doing this, i found something that confusing me. When i try to set contentDescription inside `apply` scope, AS tell me to add `else` branch. Here is the code:

```
// This one needs [else] branch
when (itemViewType) {
  R.layout.type1 -> {
    rightImage.apply {
      setOnClickListener(null)
      visibility = View.VISIBLE
      isClickable = false
      contentDescription = null
    }
  }
  R.layout.type2 -> {}
  else -> {
    // this needs to be added
  }
}

// This one does not
when (itemViewType) {
  R.layout.type1 -> {
    with(rightImage) {
      setOnClickListener(null)
      visibility = View.VISIBLE
      isClickable = false
      contentDescription = null
    }
  }
  R.layout.type2 -> {}
  // no [else] needed
}
```

And what makes me even more confused is, when i move contentDescription outside of the `apply` scope, the else is not needed.

```
// This one does not too
when (itemViewType) {
  R.layout.type1 -> {
    rightImage.apply {
      setOnClickListener(null)
      visibility = View.VISIBLE
      isClickable = false
    }
    rightImage.contentDescription = null
  }
  R.layout.type2 -> {}
  // no [else] needed too
}
```

How can it be possible? Am i missing something? Or is it a bug?
Additional context: `when` is inside onBindViewHolder and wrapped by `with`

```
with(holder) {
    // the when
}
```

Additional info:

- Happens in both AS Stable 4.2.2 and AS Arctic Fox RC01
- Kotlin version used is 1.5.20

Comment: Do you maybe use `when` as a last statement of the lambda?

Comment: Yes, we need to see the context around the `when` block.

Comment: hi, thanks for the response, additional context has been added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[When block](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression) can either be a statement (no return value) or an expression (returns a value).

It looks like this `when` block is last statement inside a lambda that returns a value (like `run` or `let`) so its return value determines the type of value returned from outer lambda.

In your first example first branch returns `rightImage` (from `apply` block) while others "don't return anything" (implicitly returning `Unit`) so compiler determines you want to return something and so have to include all branches.

In other samples first branch doesn't return anything because it ends on a statement which is the same for other branches so `when` block implicitly returns `Unit` as well and doesn't require else branch.

Comment: is it related to apply return its receiver while with returns its result?

Comment: Yes, compiler is trying to determine return type of your `with(holder)` call so if any branch of `when` returns something (other than `Unit`) it assumes your `when` is an expression and requires explicit return value from all cases. You can either ensure all branches end with a statement (return `Unit`) or prevent compiler from treating your `when` as an expression by adding any statement below your `when` block or changing `with(holder)` to result-less scoping function like `holder.apply`.

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation, One more thing, im still confused as to why this specifically happened to `contentDescription`, would you like to explain it?

Comment: It's not specific to `contentDescription = null` really, just the fact that it's a statement (doesn't return a value).